# Can't find div-element with jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to extract the red marked Information from this website with jsoup.

[image: website]

The html text of this site is presented by the following picture. The Information i want to extract is red marked again.

[image: html code of the website]

The Problem is that i can't find the div element with the class attribute "found-elements".
My Code looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://bestmentor.edudip.com/webinar/Lebe-deine-Berufung-und-deine-Arbeit-ist-Liebe/89620").get();           
        Elements ereignisse = doc.select("div#rating-entries div.found-elements article.rating div.text p");
        //Elements ereignisse = doc.select("body div#com-edudip-main-container div#content div.bottom div.academy-sidebar div.box div.ratings-exist div#rating-entries div.found-elements");        

        System.out.println(ereignisse.size());
        // Selektierte Elemente ausgeben ohne HTML-Tags
        for (Element e : ereignisse) {

            System.out.println(e.cssSelector());
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It would be really kind if somebody could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) experience with JSoup, the elements you get from the document will be the top-level elements. Thus, the div you want is actually an element of div#ratings-exist, which is an element of a higher div, etc. I think if you start with div.com-edudip-main-container and drill down in your select, you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but thats what I tried in the 5th line of my code which is marked as a comment.

Comment: I guess, the parts you're looking for are dynamic content (content that is delivered after page load)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are targeting content that is loaded via ajax after the page load. Jsoup does not execute script, but as an alternative you could switch to using a headless web browser such as [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)